# Automatically decide the final quality for adaptive image compression

Tags: image, imagemagick, compression

I have seen few websites like compressjpeg, kraken, tinyjpg and several others who decides optimum quality while compressing. If images are of quality 99 they will compress sometimes to 94 quality and sometimes to 70 level.

I tried to study their pattern and found that all of them are using imagemagick and most probably they have some tables which reads the rgb pattern of those images and decides what should be the optimum compression level.

I want quality to be dynamic for all images instead of the below imagemagick command, I am using currently:-

```
    convert -quality 70% input.jpg output.jpg
```

Here is few images and their corresponding quality after compression

```
Name    R   G   B   Overall Size    width   height  Tinyimg size    Tinypng compression     original
7.jpg   95.0354 120.168 158.313 124.506 266 1920    1200    159.8   70  91
2.jpg   155.466 126.892 121.507 134.622 59  720 378 55.3    92  94
3.jpg   230.791 230.596 230.532 230.64  28.5    720 378 10.3    69  94
1.jpg   74.8786 99.9428 101.71  92.1772 33.5    650 400 32.8    64  69
4.jpg   235.647 52.3033 50.1626 112.704 384 400 250 25.3    95  99
9.jpg   194.461 180.839 183.859 186.386 12.71   300 188 12.9    75  75
6.jpg   170.337 169.707 153.873 164.639 6.69    184 274 6.9 74  74
5.jpg   154.196 130.809 111.683 132.229 8.5 259 194 8.5 74  74
8.jpg   162.161 184.608 194.416 180.395 6.04    126 83  5.9 89  89
```

Any guidance will be useful.

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: @MarkSetchell automatically choose best quality while compressing images using imagemagick

Comment: The best quality is 100%. Everything else is a subjective trade-off between quality, size and time to compress. If you explicitly set the quality to 70%, it is going to be static, not dynamic.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thats what i am trying to figure out. if u have used tinypng u would have noticed that for every compressed image quality is different. they are deciding optimum quality i dont know how

Comment: If you specify an output file size rather than a quality, then ImageMagick can choose the best quality that achieves that file size. See jpeg:extent at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_write

Answer (score 2):

I was going to put this as a comment, but I decided to put it as an answer so folks can add/remove arguments and conclusions.

I don't believe there is *an optimum quality setting*. I think it depends on the purpose of the image and the content of the image - maybe other things too.

If the image has lots of smooth gradients, you will need a higher quality setting than if the image has loads of (high frequency) details many of which can be lost without perceptible loss of quality.

If the purpose of the image is as a web preview, it can have a far lower quality setting than if the purpose of the image is to pass a piece of fine art landscape/portrait photography to a printer or a customer who has paid £1,000 for it (I'm looking at you Venture UK).

One thing you can do is set the maximum file size you wish to achieve, but that disregards all the above:

```
convert -size 2048x2048 xc:gray +noise random -define jpeg:extent=100KB out.jpg
```

I guess I am saying *"it depends"*.

Comment: how it can be an answer. how about file size of 10 kb?? u want to convert them to 100kb??? how to detect high frequesncy in images? using imagemagick

Comment: If the image is already below your target image size, you obviously don't bother reducing the quality. It is not a magic bullet that can decide everything for you automatically, which is why I said *"it depends"*. You can detect high frequencies with Fourrier analysis, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jpeg-archive](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/jpeg-archive). This utility provides dynamic compression using various metrics such as SSIM, Multi-SSIM and Smallfry. The command you should try for is:-

```
jpeg-recompress --accurate -m smallfry --quality high image.jpg compressed.jpg
```

Note, that this method keeps subsampling on by default and should be kept so for the good size reduction.

IMO, Guetzli is right now not good for production, especially for large number of images.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Google's [Guetzli](https://github.com/google/guetzli/).

See explanations [here](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/03/google-jpeg-guetzli-encoder-file-size/).

Comment: It will take years to complete the job. its damm slow and consumes entire cpu

Comment: CPU-intensive, yes, but still usable. But in any case either you apply a blanket compression level (btw don't forget to use chroma subsampling, best bang for the buck in JPEG compression), or you try things to optimize (and Guetzli will likely be better at this game than you).